# Laravel-Mix using webpack: JQuery is not autoloaded

Tags: javascript, laravel, webpack, laravel-mix

I am trying to compile my Laravel Project with ***Laravel-Mix***, but i get a problem where jQuery is not autoloaded in the browser even with the mix.autoload directive:

> bootstrap.min.js:6 Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires
>   jQuery
>       at bootstrap.min.js:6

As you can see, i include bootstrap in a script tag at the bottom of the page, and jquery is part on my dependencies in npm package.json.

**index.blade.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Hello</p>
        <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="{{ asset(mix('js/bundle.js')) }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**webpack.mix.js**

```
const { mix } = require('laravel-mix');

mix.autoload({
    jquery: ['$', 'jQuery', 'window.jQuery'],
});

mix.js(['assets/js/script.js'], 'public/js/bundle.js');

if (mix.inProduction()) {
    mix.disableNotifications();
    mix.version();
}
```

Comment: I believe you should place bundle.js above bootstrap.min.js? If that doesn't work I would see about looking at this thread: https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/646 - adding bootstrap.min.js to `mix.js()` should remove this error but you may not want to do that I understand.

Comment: I would like to create 2 files to include in my blade template in fact: bundle.js & vendor.js. Is it possible to create vendor.js using mix.extract and specifying the path of a internal library file ?

Answer (score 3):

Install jQuery and Popper.

```
npm i jquery
npm i popper.js
```

In your /resources/js/bootstrap.js.

```
try {
    window.Popper = require('popper.js').default;
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
```

In webpack.mix.js.

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
```

In your Blade template.

```
<script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```